# Mongoose relationship

Tags: database, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm studying Mongodb and I'm using Mongoose and I would like to create a very dynamic registration process. I managed the first step of the registration using Passport and everything works fine, I created the user and it is present on the DB. Now my registration process will continue and user have to select a "role": What kind of user you are? There are 2 options: "basic" and "advanced". Basic has just 3 properties and advanced has the 3 basic properties plus few others.

I need to extend the `userSchema` or to add new fields based on that role but after a week it doesn't work yet and I tried many `NPM` like: **mongoose-relationship** or **mongoose-schema-extend**.

This is basically what I have:

```
userSchema = new Schema({
   id           : Number,
   email        : { type: String, required: true },
   role         : { type: String, required: true },
   profile      : { ... } // Profile fields are different for each role.
});

// profile 1
basicSchema = new Schema({
   info1        : { type: String, required: true },
   info2        : { type: String, required: true },
   info3        : { type: String, required: true }
});

// profile 2
advancedSchema = new Schema({
   info1        : { type: String, required: true },
   info2        : { type: String, required: true },
   info3        : { type: String, required: true },
   info4        : { type: String, required: true },
   info5        : { type: String, required: true },
   info6        : { type: String, required: true }
});
```

The user already exist and he is on a screen where he need to choose a role and populate the chosen profile.

For information I'm using **nodejs** and **expressjs**.

I hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: Does the user's profile object need to exists outside of the User object? Or you will always fetch it together with the User object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using mongoose-schema-extend:

Install via npm:`$ npm install mongoose-schema-extend`

**Example using your code:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    extend = require('mongoose-schema-extend');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
   id           : Number,
   email        : { type: String, required: true },
   role         : { type: String, required: true },
},{ collection : 'users' });

//profile 1
var basicSchema = userSchema.extend({
   info1        : { type: String, required: true },
   info2        : { type: String, required: true },
   info3        : { type: String, required: true }
});

//profile 2
var advancedSchema = userSchema.extend({
   info1        : { type: String, required: true },
   info2        : { type: String, required: true },
   info3        : { type: String, required: true },
   info4        : { type: String, required: true },
   info5        : { type: String, required: true },
   info6        : { type: String, required: true }
});
```

[**mongoose-schema-extend**](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongoose-schema-extend)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work if an user already exist.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want. The concept of "inheritance" and discriminatory field. Give it a shot. I used it and works wonders. Basically you have 3 types of users: basic, advanced and expert. Each is based on your core/base model and then you extend with extra properties you need, defining one inheritance per role.

This gives you a lot of advantages, mainly: mongoose will populate the appropriate model and kick any validation you have in the derived models, etc.

https://github.com/briankircho/mongoose-schema-extend

Comment: Hi @Biba, it looks good and I'm trying something but still no success... can you please provide example on using it without the id but with a specific key: value? Cheers.

Comment: The best example is right there: https://github.com/briankircho/mongoose-schema-extend. Read the section named Discriminatory key. Use the concept there to apply to your 3 Roles you want to implement.

Comment: The problem, after many try, is that I already created the User and when I choose the role and I try to create a new instance of that role it doesn't work. I need to extend an existing user, not create a new user with the whole properties...